# What is the optimal current for charging two 12V batteries in series?

Tags: current, battery-charging, lead-acid

I have to charge two 12 V, 184 Ah lead-acid batteries in a series circuit. I have read that the provided current should be the 10% of the Ah rating of the battery, e.g. in this case it would be 18.4 A for a single battery.
If this "10%" statement is true, would it be the 10% of 185 Ah or 185 + 185 Ah?

Comment: The current would remain the same in a series circuit. Of course, the charge voltage will need to be 24V or so. Most battery manufacturers will have a datasheet that should tell you what voltage/current for charging. I’d suggest you find the one for your battery.

Comment: Note that lead acid batteries are normally charged by constant voltage.

Comment: The charging voltage for a 24V series lead acid battery should be around 27.6V or higher (look it up in the datasheet, where you can also find the rcommended charging phases and charging currents). With only 24V you will not charge them fully and they will be damaged after a few cycles.

Comment: You may need BMS to prevent overvoltage in series. But 5 to 20% sounds right.

Comment: @Kartman lead acid batteries are charged by variety of algorithms, the most popular (in motor vehicles) being CC/CV (constant current limited by the alternator rating and then constant voltage limited by the voltage regulator). Starter batteries are specifically designed for this kind of charging and are OK with 1C..1.5C in the CC part of the charging, the traction varieties will require like 0.3C or less. 3, 4, 5-stage chargers for lead-acid batteries exist as well.

Answer (score 3):

It should be 10% of 185 Ah, as two 12V 185Ah batteries in series essentially behave as one 24V 185Ah battery.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal charge method is using a Battery Balancer which will extend the weakest battery life more than the variance from 5% 20h to 20% 5h.

Also using a pulse desulfator which operates onky when charger is active extends the life by cleaning the anodes better than 14.2V per battery. Reducing CV from 28.4 to 28.2V with this also reduces acid evaporation.